# How to install flyway DB migration tool in CentOS?

Tags: flyway

I am trying to install flyway on a centOS machine.
I have downloaded Flyway command line tar file and extracted it.
I tried to execute some flyway commands but dnt work 
it says "-bash: flyway: command not found"
Did I miss anything.
Do I have to install?
I dnt find any tutorials for Installation.

Answer (score 6):

No need to install it, it's simply a shell script with a JRE, the Flyway Java libraries and associated resources.

Sounds like you need to add the location of to the `flyway` shell script to your `PATH` variable if you want to run it without being in the directory or specifying the path.

e.g.

If you have extracted `flyway-commandline-4.1.2-linux-x64.tar.gz` to `/opt/flyway/flyway-4.1.2` which looks like:

```
flyway-4.1.2
├── conf
├── flyway       # <---- The shell script
├── lib
└── ...
```

somewhere in your setup you want that on your `PATH`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/flyway/flyway-4.1.2
```

Note the [command line documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/getstarted/firststeps/commandline) mentions the first two steps as

1. download the tool and extract it
2. `cd` into the extracted directory.

Comment: Hey downvoter, how have I not lived up to your lofty expectations?